# Material-ui with React Native

Tags: react-native, material-ui

I have a pretty simple question.

I would like to start doing some react native development.

I am not quite sute about material-ui. Is it possible to use it with react native?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes. There are already packages that implement Material UI in React Native. https://github.com/react-native-material-design/react-native-material-design

Answer (score 2):

You can also use some libraries like:

1. Material React Native (MRN)
2. React Native Material Kit
3. React Native Material UI

and you can found each library from that website or github repo.

I hope this answer can help you to make good UI for your apps.

Answer (score 1):

I think for use the `material-ui` in React Native is **very possible**. In React Native you can get package (NPM as Node Package Manager) or i call that is *Nice People Matter*, thank to the nice people on the web.

Maybe you can use [react-native-material-ui](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui), if you want start to development your app with React Native and Material UI.

I hope that is helping you. Fighting!!!